Problem from Electromagnetic Induction of IE IRODOV


According to Faraday's law, a change in the flux associated with loop generates an EMF in the loop and when we are bringing the loop into the region containing field obviously the flux associated with the loop has increased from zero to certain value. Hence a current must be induced and the galvanometer must deflect.
But sir Irodov has stated there is no change in $B$ hence no EMF. But the primary condition is change in flux but not the change in $B$ associated with loop right?


One way to see it is: there are two measurement loops, one that includes the closer circular sector, and one that includes the remaining portion of the circle. The first never includes the magnetic field region, the second always includes it in its entirety. In both cases, none of the loops sees a change in the linked flux.

@Peltio Your comment should be an answer.

One way to see it, is: there are two measurement loops, one that includes the closer circular sector, and one that includes the remaining portion of the circle.
The first never includes the magnetic field region, the second always includes it in its entirety. In either case, none of the loops sees a change in the linked flux.
If you draw the situation when the probes are midway, you will see it more clearly. Color the inside of the two measuring loops.

If you want to see the jolt, once you arrive at the far side of the ring, with the probes touching each other, detach them - still joined - from the ring. You will go from no flux at all to 100% flux enclosed.

I am sorry.I still don't understand

Does the picture help, @Rishikesh ?
